# Lightbox Plus fix lightbox (don't scroll with scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, scroll, position, lightbox

I am using the following lightbox:

http://serennz.sakura.ne.jp/toybox/lightbox/

It's simple and light. However, I don't like how it follows the scrollbar. How can I stop the lightbox following the scrollbar when its displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the plugin's theme file(colorbox.css).

add `overflow:hidden!important;` to #cboxLoadedContent.

DONE.